Is this a fake Realtek Wifi dongle?
This doesn't make any sense to me and seems that it shouldn't be possible.
I bought some, supposedly RTL8821CU USB wifi adaptors.  If I put these in a Proxmox N100 machine and run 'lsusb' then they report as
Bus 001 Device 018: ID 0bda:1a2b Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188GU 802.11n WLAN Adapter (Driver CDROM Mode)

'lsusb -v -d 0bda:1a2b' includes
  idVendor           0x0bda Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
  idProduct          0x1a2b RTL8188GU 802.11n WLAN Adapter (Driver CDROM Mode)
  bcdDevice            2.00
  iManufacturer           1 Realtek
  iProduct                2 DISK
  iSerial                 0 

But, on a Raspberry Pi 4, 'lsusb' reports them as
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0bda:c820 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11ac NIC

'lsusb -v -d 0bda:c820' includes
  idVendor           0x0bda Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
  idProduct          0xc820 
  bcdDevice            2.00
  iManufacturer           1 Realtek
  iProduct                2 802.11ac NIC
  iSerial                 3 123456

Looking up the ID "0bda:c820" this does appear to match the expected RTL8821CU chipset (with a suspicious serial number!).
Is this an 8188GU (or something else) pretending to be a 8821CU?
How can the reported device IDs change like this?
N100 Proxmox:
Linux prox1 6.8.12-4-pve #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC PMX 6.8.12-4 (2024-11-06T15:04Z) x86_64 GNU/Linux
Pi 4:
Linux DesktopPi 6.6.51+rpt-rpi-v8 #1 SMP PREEMPT Debian 1:6.6.51-1+rpt2 (2024-10-01) aarch64 GNU/Linux
I've searched for fake Realtek wifi adapters and various other searches but couldn't find anything that seemed to apply.
Any ideas?
Thank you

Do you have a rule for this device in /lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules? Like ATTR{idVendor}=="0bda", ATTR{idProduct}=="1a2b", RUN+="usb_modeswitch '/%k'".

ThanksYes, the Pi has that rule (file doesn't exist on the Proxmox server)

It might be this. On my system I have /usr/share/usb_modeswitch/0bda:1a2b but but it says TargetProduct=0x331d. What does it say on the Pi?

Only thing I have under /usr/share/usb_modeswitch is
configPack.tar.gz
I also have a /var/lib/usb_modeswitch but that is empty.

So what's inside configPack.tar.gz?

Sounds like the same as yours (sorry, I didn't realise it would look in the compressed tar)...
File: 0bda:1a2b
# D-Link DWA-171 Wifi Dongle TargetVendor=0x2001 TargetProduct=0x331d StandardEject=1

Do you have /etc/usb_modeswitch.d?

Yes but it's empty

In the Proxmox system, the dongle is initially presenting itself as a USB-connected CD-ROM drive, containing the (Windows) drivers for the dongle's actual WiFi functionality. In that mode, it uses a generic product code that apparently has first been seen with the RTL8188GU dongle model that had similar self-contained driver media functionality: that's why it says (Driver CDROM Mode).
Since the Proxmox system apparently does not have usb_modeswitch (or an up-to-date configuration for it), it does not know how to access the real WiFi functionality of the dongle, and it only sees the CDROM functionality.
Your RasPi 4, however, has a pre-installed usb_modeswitch package, which detects the virtual USB CDROM vendor:product ID 0bda:1a2b, and automatically sends it the necessary command to switch it from the virtual CDROM mode to whatever the real functionality is. In this case, the command is apparently a standard CD-ROM "eject" command.
On receiving the "eject" command, the dongle assumes that either the Windows driver installation is complete or the driver was already installed, and so the dongle resets itself and now reveals its real product ID and functionality.
If you have the /etc/usb_modeswitch.d/ directory in the Proxmox system, it would mean the actual usb_modeswitch package is installed but its configuration does not include the knowledge about the 0bda:1a2b vendor:product ID. You'd only need to drop the 0bda:1a2b file extracted from the RasPi's /usr/share/usb_modeswitch.d/configPack.tar.gz into the Proxmox system's /etc/usb_modeswitch.d/ directory to make usb_modeswitch aware of what to do with your dongle.
After supplying the configuration file, you should unplug & re-plug the dongle, and now it should be visible as its real/main vendor:product ID, which is 0bda:c820.
If the Proxmox host does not have usb_modeswitch and you cannot easily install it, you might be able to use a basic eject command to do its job in this specific case. You would have to write an udev rule that kicks in once a USB device with vendor:product ID of 0bda:1a2b is detected and assigned a /dev/sr* device (as is normal for CDROM devices), and issue a corresponding eject /dev/sr<number> command for it. This should be enough to reveal the dongle's real WiFi functionality and its associated product ID, and you could then deal with the device in the usual way.

Proxmox doesn't seem to have /etc/usb_modeswitch.d/
Seems I would need to add all this then to get the device recognised correctly to then be able to pass it through to the VM.  Actually, maybe not, there are other ways than vendor:device to pass the device through - but this is my first time with Proxmox so I don't know much!
Something for me to investigate further!
Thank you both so much for your help working this out, I'm sure it wasn't half this complicated when I worked on Linux 35 years ago!

The virtual CD-ROM should get a regular SCSI CD-ROM device node assigned to it and visible in lsblk listing: probably something like /dev/sr0. If the Proxmox host has an eject command that can accept device names, you could run eject /dev/sr0 (or whatever) to do manually the same thing the usb_modeswitch would do. If it works, you might be able set up udev rules or something along the lines of: if device 0bda:1a2b is detected, then run eject /dev/sr0. And then use a separate rule (or whatever is needed) to get the 0bda:c820 passed to the VM once it appears.

Thank you.  I did have /dev/sr0 but trying to eject just hung so I rebooted the Proxmox server - seemed to not boot if the wifi dongle was in, removed dongle, let it boot, plugged dongle in and this time it was recognised correctly!  So I guess this is going to be nice and flakey and will need to try to debug / investigate udev when it just stops working again!   Maybe I should just leave my access point / gateway on the Pi that's been working fine and just move other Pis to Proxmox!   I guess I can leave them both running and see how reliable this becomes.

Sounds like the eject command expected a response, but the device just changed modes without issuing the response first - this is probably something usb_modeswitch can handle more gracefully than a regular eject command. Dual-mode devices like that can be a pain when using Linux or *BSD, although usb_modeswitch has generally become pretty good at handling them.
